# Magento filter search result by custom text

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, catalogsearch

I have created one module **Popular Search**. In this module I am adding custom popular keywords like,

1. Shirt
2. Jeans
3. Dress

Now on search result page, I want to filter the result with these keyword. I have added Popular Search on left column for search result page only.

Logic behind filtering product is, when I click on any Popular keyword, it will check product title and list the product with matching.

Let say, I have 10 products on search result page **www.demo.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=women**. Now when I will click on dress, there is only 2 product that contain dress keyword in product title. So it will only list 2 product. I have added following code, but not getting how to filter with custom text.

```
<?php
$query = strtolower($_GET['q']);
if($this->getRequest()->getControllerName()=='result' && Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName()=='catalogsearch_result_index') {
    if($query != ""){
        $filteredList = $this->getLayout()
                ->getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list')
                ->getLoadedProductCollection();
        foreach ($filteredList as $pro){
            $productNameArray[] = strtolower($pro->getName());
        }

        $collection = Mage::getModel('popularsearch/popularsearch')->getCollection();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter( 'status', '1' );
        if($collection->getSize()){
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $keywordName = strtolower($item->getKeyword());
                $keywordArray[] = $keywordName;

                foreach ($productNameArray as $proArray){
                    if( strpos( strtolower($proArray), $keywordName ) !== false ) {
                        $matchedKeywordList[] = strtolower($item->getKeyword());
                    }
                }
            }

            $matchedKeywordList = array_unique($matchedKeywordList);
            $finalLinkarray = array_merge(array_diff($matchedKeywordList, array($query)));
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php if($finalLinkarray):?>
        <dt>Popular Searches</dt>
        <dd>
            <?php foreach ($finalLinkarray as $link):?>
            <?php
                $newlink = $this->getBaseurl()."catalogsearch/result/?".$link;
            ?>
                <ol>
                    <li><a href="<?php echo $link;?>"><?php echo ucfirst($link);?></a></li>
                </ol>    
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dd>
<?php endif;?>
```

any help will be appreciated.